# With springs getHibernateTemplate, how can I get a list of users and limit the result set?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, spring-mvc

I have a spring MVC application, how can I return a list of users and limit the results?

My UserDao looks like:

```
public List<User> getUsers(int limit) {
  return super.getHibernateTemplate()????
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming you're doing this for purposes of paging.

You can create a Query and use setMaxResults and setFirstResult:

```
public List<User> getUsers(int limit)
{
    Query q = getHibernateTemplate().getSession().createQuery("from User");
    q.setFirstResult(0); // modify this to adjust paging
    q.setMaxResults(limit);
    return (List<User>) q.list();
}
```

Alternatively, use a HibernateCallback (this is probably the best method, although it's wordier):

```
    return getHibernateTemplate().executeFind(new HibernateCallback() {
        public Object doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
            Query q = session.createQuery("from User");
            q.setMaxResults(limit);
            return q.list();
        }
    });
```

Which will additionally take care of exception translation for you.

Comment: do I have to release the session?  what's the difference between getSession and gethibernatetemplate?

Comment: I just want to do this:  select * from users;  (and with the start/limit filters).

Comment: @Blankman Yes, sorry, I forgot to include getHibernateTemplate() in there.

Comment: @Blankman The callback allows Spring to handle the exception translation (checked/data-source-specific to non-checked/Spring exception hierarchy).

Comment: getHibernateTemplate() didn't have a .getSession method on it for me.  I did discover getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession() though.  Just make sure either your dao or your dao method has @Transactional on it in order to have a transaction session available.

Answer (score 5):

If you'd like to use HibernateTemplate you can do something like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<User> getUsers(final int limit) {
    return getHibernateTemplate().executeFind(new HibernateCallback<List<User>>() {
        @Override
        public List<User> doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
            return session.createCriteria(User.class).setMaxResults(limit).list();
        }
    });
}
```

---

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<User> getUsers(final int limit) {
    return getHibernateTemplate().executeFind(new HibernateCallback<List<User>>() {
        @Override
        public List<User> doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
            return session.createQuery("from User u").setMaxResults(limit).list();
        }
    });
}
```

Actually it's not recommended to use hibernate template anymore. You should inject SessionFactory instead and call [SessionFactory.getCurrentSession()](http://www.dil.univ-mrs.fr/~massat/docs/hibernate-3.1/api/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html#getCurrentSession%28%29). [Here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/orm.html#orm-hibernate-straight) is more information on how to setup it. And [here](http://blog.springsource.com/2007/06/26/so-should-you-still-use-springs-hibernatetemplate-andor-jpatemplate/) is why you should prefer SessionFactory over HibernateTemplate.

Comment: To test clients of DAOs you should mock DAOs using some of the following: [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/), [JMock](http://www.jmock.org/), [EasyMock](http://easymock.org/), etc. To test DAO classes themselves, take an attention to [DBUnit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/) to load the data and compare the ResultSets, [Spring TestContext Framework](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/testing.html#testcontext-framework) and its [support of transactions](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/testing.html#testcontext-tx).

Comment: For simple tests of DAOs you can also use some of in-memory DBs: [Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/), [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/). In that case you will have to change hibernate dialect for such tests. I'd recommend to use a database equal to production one. In that case you will be able to use vendor-specific database features. There is also a powerful library that supports a lot of features for DAO integration testing: [Unitils](http://www.unitils.org/summary.html)

Comment: Can I use sessionfactory side by side with hibernate template? I mean I am already having  a lot of implementations that are using hibernate template and I don't want to touch them and is thinking about using sessionfactory. Is there any negative to doing so? Whether this could cause commit or db locking issues under heavy load ?

Answer (score -1):

Check here to see the available methods of a HibernateTemplate:
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTemplate.html

Depending on how you want to query, there are a few different find methods that return a List.

- find(String queryString) will let you run a specific HQL query and return a list of the results.
- loadAll(Class entityClass) will return a list of all instances of a mapped class and you can filter them yourself.

Either way I'd play around with the methods in the doc to get used to HibernateTemplate.

If you just want to "select * from users", make sure you've mapped the User class and just getHibernateTemplate.loadAll(User.class);

Comment: This does not allow setting limits. LIMIT is explicitly **not** supported in Hibernate 3 HQL now, and it only worked in 2 accidentally.