# Merge multiple object in a single instance of java.lang.Object

Tags: java, oop, object, reflection

I have 3 objects (let them be object **a** of class A, object **b** of class B and object **c** of class C) and I need to combine them to a single instance of java.lang.Object (let it be **o**). So in the end object **o** will contain inside it the three objects mentioned above. Any ideas on how this one can be achieved?

Comment: `A a`, `B b` and `C c`are different types. They could have diffrerent methods. What about the behaviour of `O o`? Should it have the methods of `A`, `B` and `C`?

Comment: Yes A, B and C are of different types, but they are simple object with only properties and their getters and setters

Comment: You have not mentioned in your question that you need this for the `HibernateCallback`. Have a look on this question: [With springs getHibernateTemplate, how can I get a list of users and limit the result set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130964/with-springs-gethibernatetemplate-how-can-i-get-a-list-of-users-and-limit-the-r) You have to set the generic type parameters of the `HibernateCallback` according to your expected result type.

Comment: If the linked question doesn't help you, edit your question and provide more context informations. Show code your are struggling with.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
public class Triplet<A, B, C> {
    private final A a;
    private final B b;
    private final C c;
    Triplet(A a, B b, C c){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }
}

public class MyClassA {}
public class MyClassB {}
public class MyClassC {}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Object o = new Triplet<>(new MyClassA(), new MyClassB(), new MyClassC());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For getter , no issues you can return the current array
for setter , you can use the Collections algorithm **addAll** for exemple :

```
String[] values = { "cat", "dog", "bird" };
setArray(values);

public void setArray(String[] sourceArray){

  ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
  list.add("elephant");

  Collections.addAll(list, values);
}
```